# Simply adding a foreign key SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

I'm trying to add a foreign key constraint to my user_info table, that is a primary key in my users table (user_id):

```
ALTER TABLE user_info
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_userID
FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
REFERENCES users(user_id);
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
Error starting at line 26 in command:
ALTER TABLE user_info
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_userID
FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
REFERENCES users(user_id)
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-02298: cannot validate (CLAYBANKS.FK_USERID) - parent keys not found
02298. 00000 - "cannot validate (%s.%s) - parent keys not found"
*Cause:    an alter table validating constraint failed because the table has
           child records.
*Action:   Obvious
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add a tag for the kind of database. Looks like SQL Server, but also including the year (2008, 2012) would be helpful in getting the attention of people who can help you.

Comment: LOL: "Action: Obvious". Well, not really.

Comment: @DOK - it would be Oracle based on the "ORA-XXXXX" error code

Answer (score 6):

This error means that you have `user_id`s in your `user_info` table that are not present in the `users` table. The foreign key can therefore not be applied.

You just have to remove all orphaned records (or `UPDATE` them to `null` if possible) in the `users_info` table, or add corresponding entries in the `users` table. Try to find them before deleting or updating them, to avoid destroying important data.

For example:

```
DELETE FROM user_info i WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM users)
```

Or

```
UPDATE user_info SET user_id = NULL WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM users)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an Oracle Error (ORA-XXXXX). It means that one or more rows in your **USER_INFO** table have a **USER_ID** field not present in the referenced table, in your case the table **USERS**.

You can retrieved your non referenced id's by using this request :

```
SELECT ui.*
FROM USER_INFO ui
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM USERS u WHERE u.user_id = ui.user_id)
```